# How do I restore a minimized batch script?

Tags: batch-file, window

I have a batch script that I have minimized but at some point in the script I'd like to be able to restore the window

Can this be done?

Comment: "Batch" or "bash", and what does this have to do with programming?

Comment: can i not ask batch related questions here?

Comment: If they're about programming, sure.

Comment: well in part of my batch script that i'm currently programming i'd like the windows to unminimize ;)

Comment: This is a window management question, not a programming related question.

Comment: "I wrote a bash script, then I set my computer on fire. How can I file an insurance claim?"

Comment: Are you asking how *you* can restore the window, or are you asking how to have *the script* restore its own window?

Comment: how to have the script restore its own window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) This is a very useful tool which everyone who writes batch scripts should have in their arsenal. Here is an example of doing exactly what you want. When you run it, it will immediately minimize the script window, then in 10 seconds it will restore it.

```
@echo off
Title "My Script"
Nircmdc win min ititle "My Script"
set /a i=0
:Loop
Ping -n 1 127.0.0.1>nul
set /a i+=1
if %i% EQU 10 goto :max
Goto :loop

:Max
Nircmdc win activate ititle "My Script"
cmd /k
```

Comment: perfect little tool that last but one line is exactly what i'm after! thank you! :D